# window.location.href navigating to correct page but not updating URL

Tags: javascript, url, list-button

***What Am I doing ?***

I have this JavaScript list button 'Create Record for RecordType X' on Object B (which is child to Object A) to navigate to the correct VF page "RecordTypeX_VF" **with RetUrl** of Object B's record's Id , if selected from related list.

***Which code does that ?***

The JS button code lines responsible doing this are -

```
var recId = window.location.href.substring(window.location.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1); 

window.location.href =  '/apex/RecordTypeX_VF?retURL=/'+recId ;
```

***What is happening ?***

The page get redirected to desired VF page but the URL doesn't gets update in the browser, i.e. the same old URL gets shown.

***So, what is the problem ?***

RecordTypeX_VF fetched the RetUrl from page url and shows different Screens based on the navigation (from tab / related list). Now, that the URL isn't getting updated on navigation to RecordTypeX_VF page, the page does not get  the retURl and shows the generic view(how it should look when it is coming from tab).

Comment: why don't you try this: `window.open('/apex/RecordTypeX_VF?' 
+'retURL=/'+recId');`

Comment: Window.open will open a new tab which is not the requirement. the URL should get updated for the same tab.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is shorted now ,

> To update current page URL on navigation to other page, we should use
>   "this.parent" for constructing URL.

Thus, replacing

`window.location.href`

with

```
this.parent.location.href
```

is the answer.

> window.location.href will navigate you to the correct page but the URL
>   will persist as the older one only.

Comment: Great that you found an answer.

Answer (score 1):

this is incorrect:

```
window.location.href =  '/apex/RecordTypeX_VF?' 
    +'&retURL=/'+recId ;
```

you have an & after the ?

Change to

```
window.location.href =  '/apex/RecordTypeX_VF?retURL=/'+recId ;
```

Also, you should look into `URLFOR` instead for constructing the url

Comment: Thank you for the correction. that miss was due to removal of other parameters. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

To navigate to another url from within a lightening component you should use              `sforce.one.navigateToURL("Your_Url");`

For Salesforce Classic you could still use `window.location.href`
This is the documentation url for refrence https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.lex_prepare_vf_window.htm&type=5